failed to enroll new fingerprint on Ubuntu 24.04.01 + Asus ExpertBook P3540FA
in System --> users -->  --> Fingerprint Login --> Scan new fingerprint --> whichever fingerprint
Shows "Failed to enroll new fingerprint" immediately, even before I try to put my fingerprint.
Can it be fixed?
Thanks!

